# Delphi XE2: LIB prefix/suffix/version setting for DLL application is missing in Project | Options

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Prior to Delphi XE and below, the DLL application's project options has these setting:

1. LIB prefix
2. LIB suffix
3. LIB version

However, these settings are missing in Delphi XE2.  Is this a bug in Delphi XE2 IDE?  Or it will no longer supported in future version of Delphi IDE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These settings are only shown in the project options for a package project. The settings still take effect for DLL projects if written directly into the source with $LIBPREFIX, $LIBSUFFIX or $LIBVERSION. It's quite possible that the settings can be made directly in the .dproj file even though the IDE doesn't have UI for the settings.